# finding a href with a specific text in a table

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have an html tables and I am trying to find the row that has a href tag whose text content has the word "Unsubscribe" in it. I am using lxml, python and xpath - I can find the row using this:

```
row_to_find = table.xpath("//tr[contains(descendant::*, 'Unsubscribe')]")[0]
```

But the above does not find this inside a href.. and the following does not work..

```
row_to_find = tables.xpath(".//tr/*/a[contains(text(), 'Unsubscribe')]")
```

Comment: Please provide a sample XML and desired output for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these will work:

```
//a[.="Unsubscribe"]/ancestor::tr
//tr[.//a[.="Unsubscribe"]]
```

- The first says, *"Find an `<a>` whose text is 'Unsubscribe', and then find the ancestor `<tr>` element(s) of that."*
- The second says, *"Find a `<tr>` anywhere, but only if it has a descendant `<a>` with the text 'Unsubscribe'"*

Both will give you false positives if your table is itself wrapped in another table, and hence has another `<tr>` matching this very loose criteria. You can tighten it up by supplying a more exact path, e.g.

```
//a[.="Unsubscribe"]/parent::*/parent::tr
//tr[./*/a[.="Unsubscribe"]]
```

…or (for the first) by specifying that you only want the first (closest) `<tr>`:

```
//a[.="Unsubscribe"]/ancestor::tr[1]
```